# How to change speed of scrolling background pygame?

Tags: python, scroll, background, pygame, horizontal-scrolling

I'm making a game for Pygame, and I want the background to scroll faster, but I don't know how to. This is the code that is relevant to the scrolling background:

```
#Scrolling background

    background = "foxhabitat.jpg"
    back = pygame.image.load(background).convert()
    back2 = pygame.image.load(background).convert()

    screenWidth = 900
    back=pygame.transform.scale(back, (1000,600))
    back2=pygame.transform.scale(back, (1000,600))   

    screenscroll.blit(back, (xx,0))
    screenscroll.blit(back2,(xx-screenWidth,0))

    xx = xx + 1
    if xx == screenWidth:
        xx = 0

    msElapsed = clock.tick(500) # thought it would change speed of scrolling?
```

I've tried to change the speed of the clock.tick but it didn't do anything, and yes, I imported the clock at the beginning of the program. How do I change the
speed of the scrolling background? Oh, and screenscroll is screenscroll = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600),0,0) Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add bigger value

```
xx = xx + 2
```

That's all.

---

And use `>=` because sometimes `xx` may not be equal `screenWidth`

```
if xx >= screenWidth:
    xx = 0
```

---

`clock.tick(500)` means "give me not more than 500 FPS" but sometimes it can be less. If you have slow computer it can give you always only 25 FPS.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped!